# Regarding existence of Principal Characters for a finite group

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, analytic-number-theory

I have been self studying Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory and I have a doubt in text of Chapter 6 of the book .

Apostol mentions in section 6.5 ( Characters of finite Abelian Groups)

> Every group G has at least one character, namely the function which is identically 1 on G. This is called principal character .

My doubt is how to prove existence of such a function on every finite group ie how to prove such a character definitely exists for every finite group.

Can anyone please give explanation for this

Comment: Why are you asking for the existence of a function which is identically $1$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde how to be sure for each group such a function will definitely exist?

Comment: You wrote it down definitely. What more do you want?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde you are right. I was a bit confused.

Comment: The corresponding representation $(G,\Bbb{C})$ is $g. v= v$ for all $v\in \Bbb{C},g\in G$, the matrix of $v\to g.v$ is $\rho(g) = \pmatrix{1} $ and $tr(\rho(g))=1$